# Turn off automatic pagination of Django Rest Framework ModelViewSet

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework's `ModelViewSet` for one of my views. `ModelViewSet` uses the `ListModelMixin` which automatically paginates the results but I do not want to get the results paginated. In my API call I pass as parameter how many results I want returned but as it stands I can't get back more than 10 results in one call.

Is there a way to turn the automatic pagination off so that I can have as many results as I want returned?

Comment: ListModelMixing is very simple, (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/bb56ca46ed6c07db0146dbdc61c672ff25f127de/rest_framework/mixins.py) Looks like you could write your own mixin and just omit the lines that do the pagination.

Comment: I haven't found an easy way to turn pagination off exactly but I was able to set PAGE_SIZE in the REST_FRAMEWORK settings to a large number to allow me to get more results returned.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you are using recent versions of DRF you just need to add     `pagination_class = None` to your `ModelViewSet` definition.

```
class MyClassBasedView(ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    ...
```

You can also see some tips here https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1390

Comment: but that removes `results` attribute

Comment: @ospider why is he needed?

Comment: Sometimes you want to use the same viewset for both options. In those cases overwrite paginate_queryset method.

Answer (score 15):

ModelViewSet or mixins.ListModelMixin automatically create pagination for us. You can stop it by
**paginator = None**

```
class NotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
     queryset = Notes.objects.all()
     serializer_class = NotesWriteSerializer
     paginator = None
```

Answer (score 5):

And if you want paginator disabled for just one action:

```
@property
def paginator(self):
    self._paginator = super(NotesViewSet, self).paginator
    if self.action == 'the_action_you_want_pagination_disabled':
        self._paginator = None
    return self._paginator
```

use this in your `ModelViewSet`.

Answer (score 3):

In settings.py for global

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': None,
    'PAGE_SIZE': 99999999, # a very large number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a large number of items for specific view, keeping the `results` attribute and default pagination number for all others views, using a custom Pagination Class like this:

```
from rest_framework import pagination, permissions, viewsets


class FooViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   class CustomFooPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
      page_size = 10000

   pagination_class = CustomFooPagination
   queryset = FooModel.objects.filter(enabled=True)
   serializer_class = FooSerializer
   permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via two way either one you like or choose for you

> Paginator Property

```
class MyClassBasedView(ModelViewSet):
    pagintor = None
```

> Paginatior Class

```
class MyClassBasedView(ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
```

> Details about why we use methods

**Reason of using these ways because the `ModelViewSet` class inherits `GenericView` that inherits `GenericAPIView`.**

`pagination class` is a property of `GenericAPIView` that can be used to set pagination class or None for no pagination

Reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/aed7761a8d7e1691a4f4bbf9c83a447dac44d92a/rest_framework/generics.py#L158

`paginator` is also a property of `GenericAPIView` that can be used to set paginator class or None for no pagination

Reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L46

[image: see the django rest framework code on Github]

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py